# Catch "rm: fts_read: No such file or directory" error and continue

Tags: bash, macos, unix, rm

I goofed my Macbook real good. I moved some Time Machine backups from my external drive into `Trash` and quickly realized that was a horrible mistake. I can't put them back and I can't delete them. So far I've been running `rm` with a helper function called `bypass` that is allowing me to skirt Apple's protection of deleting backups.

Anyways, I have a command

```
sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass rm -rfv /Volumes/*/.Trashes
```

which for brevity can be referred to as

```
sudo bypass rm -rfv /Volumes/*/.Trashes
```

that keeps randomly getting interrupted by `rm: fts_read: No such file or directory`. I think fts_read is essentially a UNIX kernel function that gets into filespace and is read as a file during very verbose recursive `rm` calls. So I want to catch `fts_read` and restart my `sudo bypass rm -rfv /Volumes/*/.Trashes`. I don't know bash that well, but here's some pseudocode of my thoughts:

```
try:
  sudo bypass rm -rfv /Volumes/*/.Trashes
except 'rm: fts_read: No such file or directory':
  sudo bypass rm -rfv /Volumes/*/.Trashes
```

Basically right now I'm manually restarting the command every time I get the error, but this process is taking dozens of hours so it'd be nice if it could restart itself.

Comment: How did you solve it finally?

Comment: I'm not sure, although perhaps try wrapping your commands in something like python? That way you can utilize try/catch and still make command line `exec` calls @ebaynaud

Answer (score 2):

One possible option could be a while loop that requires the failure of the previous command? example:

```
counter=0
cd "not a real place" #get the initial error code
while [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo 'words'
    (( counter++ ))
    (( counter > 10 ))
done
```

This will keep going until `(( counter > 10 ))` returns 0, i.e., evaluates to true. You should be able to do something similar with your command:

```
sudo bypass rm -rfv /Volumes/*/.Trashes
while [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; do
    sudo bypass rm -rfv /Volumes/*/.Trashes
done
```

I doubt this is a *good* solution, but it's *a* solution.